# Compilando e rodando a aplicação java e maven com o mesmo encoding

Tags: java, maven, codificação-de-caracteres

Eu tenho uma aplicação que estou compilando usando o maven pela linha de comando. No meu `pom.xml` especifiquei o *encoding* utilizando:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

E na hora que vou rodar a aplicação utilizo o seguinte comando:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar myJar.jar
```

Porem, quando eu rodo a aplicação no prompt aparecem caracters estranhos... tipo:

`ADVERT├èNCIA ou INFORMA├ç├òES`

Comment: Está utilizando qual ide?

Comment: Utilizo o eclipse, mas estou compilando e executando pelo prompt.

Comment: Então, testa alterar o encoding do arquivo diretamente pelo eclipse. Vai em Window > Preferences > General > Content Types.  Lá você poderá alterar todos os .java ou qualquer outra extensão para UTF-8.

Comment: Já está como UTF-8